# Power series representation of $f(x) = \frac{x-1}{x+2}$

Tags: sequences-and-series, power-series

What I did so far:

\begin{align*}
\frac{x-1}{x+2}&=(\frac{x-1}{2})\frac{1}{1-(-\frac{x}{2})} \\
&=(\frac{x-1}{2})\sum_{n=1}^\infty (-\frac{x}{2})^n\\
&= (x-1)\sum_{n=1}^\infty \frac{-x^n}{2^{n+1}}
\end{align*}

But i'm stuck there.

Comment: Do you need to know how to derive the power series or do you just need the answer? If you just need the answer, Wolfram Alpha can do it for you: https://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=(x-1)%2F(x%2B1)+power+series

Comment: You've done the hard part. Work out the first few coefficients for $(x-1)(a_0 + a_1x + a_2x^2 + \cdots)$. You should see the pattern.

Comment: I need to know how to do it, my answer book has the answer, I just need to understand the steps!

Comment: Note you should have $\left(-\frac{x}{2}\right)^n$, not $\left(\frac{x}{2}\right)^n$. You can distribute now and write $(x-1)\displaystyle\sum_{n=1}^\infty \frac{x^n}{2^{n+1}}=\displaystyle\sum_{n=1}^\infty \frac{x^{n+1}}{2^{n+1}}-\displaystyle\sum_{n=1}^\infty \frac{x^n}{2^{n+1}}$. Now re-index the first sum and combine like powers of $x$ to find the coefficient of $x^n$.

Comment: Also note that development you did is valid as long as $\left|\frac x2\right|<1\iff |x|<2\;$ .

Comment: the OP forgot a minus before $\frac{x}{2}$

Comment: Edited development.

Answer (score 1):

But then you're already done...That can't be put in any form that will be nicer imo.

You could also try

$$\frac{x-1}{x+2}=1-\frac3{x+2}=1-\frac32\frac1{1+\frac x2}=1-\frac32\sum_{n=0}^\infty\frac{(-1)^nx^n}{2^n}=\sum_{n=0}^\infty a_nx^n$$

with

$$a_0=1-\frac32=-\frac12\;,\;\;a_n=\frac{3(-1)^{n+1}}{2^{n+1}}\;,\;\;n\ge1$$

Answer (score 0):

$$f(x)=\frac{x-1}{x+2}=1-\frac{3}{x+2}=1-\frac{3}{2}\frac{1}{1+\frac{x}{2}}\to\\
f(x)=1-\frac{3}{2}\sum_{n=0}^{\infty}(-1)^n\left(\frac{x}{2}\right)^n
$$
There are several ways to represent this exression. If you'd like to have everything under one sum, you can do following:
$$
1=\frac{1}{2}2\to 1=\frac{1}{2}\sum_{n=0}^{\infty}\left(\frac{1}{2}\right)^n=\sum_{n=0}^{\infty}\left(\frac{1}{2}\right)^{n+1}\\
f(x)=\sum_{n=0}^{\infty}\left(\left(\frac{1}{2}\right)^{n+1}+\frac{3}{2}(-1)^{n+1}\left(\frac{x}{2}\right)^n\right)
$$

Answer (score 0):

An alternate approach:
\begin{align}
\frac{x-1}{x+2} &= \frac{x + 2 - 3}{x+2} = 1 - \frac{3}{2 + x} = 1 - \frac{3}{2} \, \frac{1}{1 + \frac{x}{2}} \\
&= 1 - \frac{3}{2} \, \sum_{n=0}^{\infty} (-1)^{n} \, \frac{x^{n}}{2^{n}} \\
&= 1 - \frac{3}{2} + \sum_{n=1}^{\infty} \frac{(-1)^{n}}{2^{n}} \, x^{n} \\
&= \sum_{n=0}^{\infty} a_{n} \, x^n
\end{align}
which leads to
$$ a_{0} = - \frac{1}{2} \hspace{5mm} a_{n} = \frac{3 \, (-1)^{n+1}}{2^{n}}, n \ge 1   $$